# BufferedReader and Sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, http, web, stream

Suppose I'm using a Socket InputStream like this,in order to read the following data:
(first part encoded in ASCII)

```
    the rest of this message is binaryCRLF  
    01100110010...
```

code:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = in.readLine();
```

what I expect at this point,is that `line` contains the text:

> the rest of this message is binary

Then I would like to use the original socket InputStream:

```
 InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();  
    ...
```

to read the binary part of the message.

Now, what if the BufferedReader has buffered some of the binary data,
this would be a problem because I would miss part of the data.
Am I misssing something ?

Comment: Does your approach work?

Comment: This is more of a lack of understanding on how buffered input stream works than a practical issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the source of `BufferedReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/BufferedReader.java#88) you will see that the default buffer size is 8192. Because of this the call of [`readLine()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28%29) will read more than the bytes of the first line into the buffer.

Use a different approach. Buffer the input and read it twice.

Comment: My example is similar to what browsers have to do in order to show a web page content to the user.how do they handle this issue?

Comment: They don't mix characters and bytes. HTTP is a protocl with headers like Content-Type and Content-Length. Take a look at the source code of a HTTP parser.

Comment: As part of the same issue, the API of InputStreamReader reports that it can buffer bytes,though it is not a buffered stream.what does it mean ?

Answer (score -1):

try

---

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line ="";
String buffer="";
while((buffer= in.readLine()) != null){ 
  line.concat(buffer); 
}
```

this way, till you have data in the BufferedReader, you would read it into line and would not loose any buffered data. Cheers.. :)

---

Also for faster IO, use nio(New Input Output) libraries, especially ByteBuffer objects, where you can also flush the data from the stream using flush().

Comment: The `BufferedReader` will convert the bytes into characters. Since the second 'line' is binary, this will not work.

Comment: Yeah.. use `ByteBuffer`  objects from nio which reads character by character, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html